# Rearrange array elements into two new arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, jqplot

I have a json-encoded array with 5000 lines all looking like the following:

```
[2013-01-01 07:00, 10, 50]
```

In order to draw a jqplot with two y-axis, I need to get two different arrays out of this one looking like the following:

```
array1: [2013-01-01 07:00, 10]
array2: [2013-01-01 07:00, 50]
```

What I tried is the following approach but it doesn't seem to work well:

```
var data= <?php echo json_encode($dataarray); ?>;
var array1= [];  
var array2 = [];

for(var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++){
  array1[i] = array1[i][0]+array1[i][1];
  array2[i] = array2[i][0]+array2[i][2];
};
```

Could somebody help or is there even an easier way to draw the 2-y-axis plot with my original array, without the need to split the array elements?

Comment: Can you provided a few more lines of your input example

Comment: `array1.push(array1[i][0]).push(array1[i][1]);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they are all in an array and that the items are all the same shape, you could use the following piece of code:

```
var data = [
  ['2013-01-01 07:00', 10, 50],
  ['2013-01-01 08:00', 20, 70]
]

var array1 = data.map(function(item){ return [item[0], item[1]]});
var array2 = data.map(function(item){ return [item[0], item[2]]});
```

Alternatively, you could change your original approach:

```
var array1 = [];  
var array2 = [];

for(var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++){
  array1.push([data[i][0], data[i][1]]);
  array2.push([data[i][0], data[i][2]]);
};
```

Finally, i think arrays are usually better to store the same kind of items. Your original data might better suited to be structured like this:

```
var data = [
  { date: '2013-01-01 07:00', first : 10, second: 50},
  { date: '2013-01-01 07:00', first : 20, second: 70}
]
```

The same solution works with only minor modifications.

Comment: This is viable solution, of course this mean you have to walk the array twice giving time complexity of O(2n) which can certainly be improved upon if one uses more manual approach.

Comment: @MikeBrant You are correct that there is a performance hit there, even though O(2n) === O(n). The performance hit is the extra comparison and incrementation, which for the 5000 elements mentioned in the question is minuscule.

Comment: Your O(n) approach need to get data from 2nd dimension of data array (i.e. `data[i][0]`)

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked perfectly!
What do you mean by your structuring approach?

Comment: @user3207478 As i said, you generally want arrays to hold N of the same items, not have an array to hold a timestamp, an index and a price. JavaScript objects are better suited for that, because you know what one means when he says `item.timestamp` instead of a generic `item[2]`.

Comment: @Tibos: I see. I understand your point. Thanks a lot. I just kind of have to use the array, because I need to draw a jqplot with the data and the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Here is O(n) time complexity approach:

```
var data= <?php echo json_encode($dataarray); ?>;
var array1 = [];  
var array2 = [];

var len = data.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    array1.push([data[i][0], data[i][1]]);
    array2.push([data[i][0], data[i][2]]);
}
```